# I have a challenging MySQL SELECT query that involves stock and threshold bondary

Tags: mysql, database, select, stock, commercial-application

I Have a MySQL DataBase which contains two tables linked with a foreign key:

`MatPr(id, Designation, threshold_stock)`

And

`MvtStock_MatPr(id, Qte_Mvt, Qte_Tot,idMatPr)`

What I want is to get the last Qte_tot, Designation,threshold_stock where threshold_stock>qte_tot 
I tried this code and did not work:

```
SELECT MvtStock_MatPr.id,idMatPr, Nom, threshold_stock, Qte_Tot 
FROM MvtStock_MatPr, MatPr 
WHERE MatPr.id=MvtStock_MatPr.idMatPr AND  threshold_stock>Qte_Tot
```

Here is Sample Data set:

```
mysql> SELECT MvtStock_MatPr.id,idMatPr, Designation, threshold_stock, Qte_Tot FROM MvtStock_MatPr, MatPr WHERE MatPr.id=MvtStock_MatPr.idMatPr AND threshold_stock>Qte_Tot ORDER
```

BY id,idMatPr;

| id | idMatPr | Dsignation| threshold_stock| Qte_Tot |

|  1 |       1 | bakra  |   120 |      10 |

|  2 |       2 | zipper |   130 |      20 |

|  3 |       1 | bakra  |   120 |      30 |

|  7 |       2 | zipper |   130 |      50 |

4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM MatPr;
```

| id | Designation| threshold_stock|

|  1 | bakra  |   120 |

|  2 | zipper |   130 |

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM MvtStock_MatPr;
```

| id | DateMvt    | Qte_Mvt | Qte_Tot | idMatPr |

|  1 | 2016-01-01 |      10 |      10 |       1 |

|  2 | 2016-02-02 |      20 |      20 |       2 |

|  3 | 2016-03-03 |      20 |      30 |       1 |

|  4 | 2016-03-03 |     100 |     130 |       1 |

|  5 | 2016-03-03 |      50 |     180 |       1 |

|  6 | 2016-03-03 |      20 |     200 |       1 |

|  7 | 2016-03-05 |      30 |      50 |       2 |

7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

What I would like to get is:

| id | idMatPr | Dsignation| threshold_stock| Qte_Tot

|  3 |       1 | bakra  |   120 |      30 |

|  7 |       2 | zipper |   130 |      50 |
+----+---------+--------+-------+---------+

Thanks for your contributions

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. It should be something that describes the actual problem you're facing or question you're asking, and should be specific enough to have meaning to a future reader who sees it in a search result. *I have a complicated query* is totally useless in that regard - everyone can say their query is *complicated*, whether it actually is or not. Your question is not too clear, either; some sample data from both tables and the output you'd like to get from that sample data with your query would help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
Select m1.id,m1.idMatpr,m.threshold_stock,m.Qte_Tot 
From MvtStock_Matpr m1 join Matpr m
On m1.idMatPr=m.id and m.threshold_stock>m1.Qte_Tot
```

Comment: Not helpfull, that produces the same result I get : 4rows and I want to get only 2 rows as I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I completely follow what your problem is: is it selecting just one row from a result set?  If so, does a subquery fix your problem?

```
SELECT *
FROM MatPr
WHERE ID = (
  SELECT idMatPr 
  FROM MvtStock_MatPr, MatPr 
  WHERE MatPr.id = MvtStock_MatPr.idMatPr 
    AND threshold_stock > Qte_Tot
  LIMIT 1
)
```

If you want to select just the rows from `MatPr`, does this work for you?

```
SELECT MatPr.*
FROM MvtStock_MatPr, MatPr 
WHERE MatPr.id = MvtStock_MatPr.idMatPr 
  AND threshold_stock > Qte_Tot
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4ef50/2

Comment: No. Iwant to get all MatPr that have the condition  threshold_stock > Qte_Tot

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select * from 
   ( SELECT MvtStock_MatPr.id,idMatPr,Designation, threshold_stock, Qte_Tot 
     FROM MvtStock_MatPr join MatPr 
     on MatPr.id=MvtStock_MatPr.idMatPr 
     where threshold_stock>Qte_Tot 
     order by DateMvt desc 
   ) T 
 group by T.idMatPr
```

Comment: Or you can order by MvtStock_MatPr.id desc as the DateMvt column is not datetime and can be repeated in more than one row

Comment: That was so close... This query gets two rows but the unneeded ones: rows with MvtStoc_MatPr.id 1and 2 .What I want to get is the rows with MvtStock_MatPr.id 3 and 7 .

Comment: I just tried it and it gets the MvtStock_MatPr.id ids 3 and 7 but the column is renamed to 'id' instead of  MvtStock_MatPr.id, can you paste the results to see what data I have wrongly inserted in the tables?

Comment: | id | idMatPr | De|signation threshold_stock| Qte_Tot |

|  1 |       1 | bakra  |   120 |      10 |

|  2 |       2 | zipper |   130 |      20 |

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: I can't get what's wrong, but I am getting the results with 3 and 7, maybe something in the table creation is different, here is a sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e916/1

Comment: You forgot to paste the string, are the tables different from the ones in the fiddle?

Comment: I believe  you but when I tried on the REAL environment = MySQL 5.7 it doesn't deliver the expected result as in SqlFiddle !